# How can i change logo DE on LightDM

Tags: gnome, lightdm

How can I change this with my own logo

i'm using ubuntu 18.04

[image: here my pict]

I have searched but till now I haven't got the solution

Comment: what is your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: i'm using 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:
1. Ubuntu 18.04
2. lightdm is installed via `sudo apt install lightdm`

*steps to achieve

1. make your `.png` image ready.
2. resize the image some thing like 100x100pixels or 50x50pixels anything but compare to the original size 22x22 pixels or rectangular shapes also Ok and rename it as `ubuntu_badge.png`

*`22x22` Pixel size is highly recommended.

3. open the folder `/usr/share/unity-greeter`
4. take backup of the file `ubuntu_badge.png` anywhere and delete it.

[image]

5. paste the image which is our preferred one in step 2.
6. close & reboot to see the change.

example pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]